# How to use the AWS api-gateway C++ SDK

Tags: c++, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I'm using C++ client to invoke AWS API gateway functions. currently I'm using curl to directly send HTTP requests to the APIs. I downloaded the AWS C++ SDK and I can see that there is a "apigateway" folder inside the SDK package.

However, I could not find any information how to use this apigateway SDK - how to invoke API gateway functions and how to integrate with authorization as specified in Amazon Signature V4 documentation:

[When you use the AWS Command Line Interface (AWS CLI) or one of the AWS SDKs to make requests to AWS, these tools automatically sign the requests for you with the security credentials you specify when you configure the tools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html)

Is there any information available of how to work with the apigateway SDK?